# how to get ethernet Ip and public Ip?

Tags: php, ip-address

I can find a lot of information how to get public Ip but not the ethernet one.
I am not sure if the you should get the ethernet one as easy as the public one in php.

Comment: By `ethernet one` do you mean LAN address?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the clients internal IP? You can't. That information isn't available for external servers (nor should it be).

Comment: I ment the user device id.

Comment: A server only knows the IP address of the machine that's connecting to it, which is typically a router and sometimes a proxy. Some proxies add a `x-forwarded-for` HTTP header as a commodity (not really something to be trusted), but I suspect routers don't (a LAN address is private to that LAN).

Comment: Alright, so there is no way to get the device Ip, I mean for ex. a user logs from a PC. to a website and I need to know the user device IP.  So if someone would try to log from a diffrent IP it would send an email to the user with the information "If that is you".

Comment: That's what public IP and maybe `x-forwarded-for` are used for. Private addresses aren't unique.